# Localization of a principal ring is principal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I'm trying to prove that the localization $S^{-1}A$ is a principal ring. Here, $A$ is a principal ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$. Furthermore we assume $0 \notin S$.

The term *principal ring* is used in Lang's algebra, referring to a nontrivial commutative ring whose all ideals are principal. It allows zero divisors, which is the only difference form PID.

Anyway I start with an ideal $\mathfrak a'$ in $S^{-1}A$. Let $f:A \to S^{-1}A$ be the canonical map. Then $f^{-1}(\mathfrak a')$ is a principal ideal, say $aA$, in $A$.

Now $\mathfrak a'$ seems to be the principal ideal $(a/1)(S^{-1}A)$. Showing that this ideal is contained in $\mathfrak a'$ is easy, but I got stuck to show the converse.

Any braekthrough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an ideal $\mathfrak a\leqslant S^{-1}A$ and consider the underlying ideal in $A$, i.e. $\mathfrak a\cap A$. By assumption, this ideal is principal and hence $\mathfrak a\cap A=aA$ for some $a\in A$. Let $x\in\mathfrak a$. Then there is some $s\in S$ such that $sx\in A$ by construction and hence $sx\in \mathfrak a\cap A=aA$. So $x\in a(S^{-1}A)$ lifting the principal ideal to the localization. This shows at once that $\mathfrak a$ is principal with generator $a$.

---

The map $\mathfrak a\mapsto\mathfrak a\cap A$ is a left inverse of your canonical map. One can show that composing these the other way around is the identity on prime ideals disjoint from $S$, which might be an interesting fact. See Milne's *Algebraic Number Theory* $§1$ for the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mrtaurho. But how can I regard a ring as a subset of its localization? I mean, is there a canonical _inclusion_?

Comment: @AlpacaParka Indeed, there is! The map $x\mapsto x/1$ is this canonical inclusion (it is  fact even universal as such).

Comment: dear @mrtaurho +1, but I would be cautious about the use of the word "inclusion" here, since that map will of course not necessarily be injective. for instance $\mathbb{Z}\big/6\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subring of its localization at the prime ideal $2\mathbb{Z}\big/6\mathbb{Z}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\big/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Of course! I only realised afterwards that it might not be the best word possible (or, worse, is really misleading). Sticking to "canonical map" would've been better.

Comment: This seems obvious, but how do we have $\mathfrak{a} \cap A$ is an ideal in $A$? Is this a property of quotient rings, or something more general?

Comment: @Migillope Think of the expression $\mathfrak a\cap A$ as $\varepsilon^{-1}(\mathfrak a}$ (=the preimage of $\mathfrak a$) with $\varepsilon\colon x\mapsto x/1$. Then this becomes a standard fact about ring homomorphisms.